# How to improve many level dependant destroy performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, destroy, cascading-deletes

In my project there are many models with `has_many` association and `dependant: :destroy` flag. Also, each model have other `belong_to` associations with the `dependant: :destroy` flag. This models are *nested* between each other so when a `destroy` is executed on the top one, **Rails** triggers *cascading* destroy on children models.

Apart from that, models have `callbacks` that execute `before_destroy`.

The following represents what I described above:

```
class Model1Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2_examples, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :other1_example, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :other2_example, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Model2Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1_example
  has_many :model3_examples, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :other3_example, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :other4_example, :dependent => :destroy

  before_destroy :update_something_on_model1
  before_destroy :check_some_inconsistence
end

class Model3Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model2_example

  belongs_to :other5_example, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :other6_example, :dependent => :destroy

  before_destroy :update_something_on_model2
  before_destroy :check_some_inconsistence
end
```

Given that on average `Model2Example` holds about 100+ instances of `Model3Example` when the `Model1Example` `destroy` is triggered many **SQL queries** are triggered (10k+) because deletion is record by record and also all rules are executed for every instance...and this takes a lot more than what a user could wait for such a simple action.

I could fix this performance issue by using `dependant: :delete_all` on the `has_many` associations instead, because I don't really care that all this rules are executed when I trigger `Model1Example` `destroy`.

But the problem is that when I execute (from elsewhere in the app) a `Model2Example` `destroy` is in my interest that all rules are executed (specially `Model3Example` rules for each instance), and the previous mentioned approach brakes this.

Is there a "**Rails** way" to achieve a performance improvement for this case? Or should I just use **SQL** for `Model1Example` deletion?

Also, if I have to use this approach and I wanted to check some basic stuff before destroying `Model1Example`, where is the best place to do this validation? controller?

Comment: Have you considered to put all this into a background worker? This question has a very good answer for this sort of problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179141/handle-dependent-destroy-via-active-jobs

Comment: Thanks for that @ThomasR.Koll. Actually I did think about that, in fact, it was my first idea, but then I thought: how do I let the user know when deletion is completed? The delete flag is a good idea I haven't thought about, but I would have to go to every place where `Model1Example` is used and filter out the flagged as deleted instances, correct?

Comment: Thinking about it, I should also flag the `Model2Example` children instances because I can access them from elsewhere - it wouldn't be nice letting the user access those instances while they're being deleted. Also, if `Model3Example` instances where accesible from elsewhere I'd have to do the same.

Comment: Personally I use a paranoia gem in my models (i'm Mongoid btw) so I have a deleted_at timestamp anyways. I'm sure there's one for ActiveRecord and the likes.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll you might as well put your tips in an answer so I can at least upvote your ideas ;)

Comment: next time. happy to see you actually want to hand our upvotes :) far too few do that.

Comment: @RodrigoMartinez if you are using a Rails version compatible with active job you could use after_perform to broadcast the result of the destroy action after the job has finished. At least that's what i do to create progress bars in the UI for background tasks that are not instant.